# add a getdate() default value while adding a column

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Useally if I want to add default value , I use this way

```
ALTER TABLE tab1 ADD  coll datetime DEFAULT '11-01-15' NOT NULL
```

however I want to add default value as the getdate().
so If use the below I got the below error

```
ALTER TABLE tab1 ADD  coll datetime DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL

error: ALTER TABLE 'tab1' failed. Default cannot be an expression when adding non-NULL column 'tab1'. Use a default value instead.
```

what I want is the default value is the getdate(). how to do that when adding a new datetime column ?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @kebs ok ill edit my question and make it more clear

Comment: You mean like `NOW()`? O_o

Comment: @JonStirling I edit my question .. is it clear now ?

Comment: @JonStirling I want the default value to be getdate(), now() is throwing error , I am using ase isql

Comment: @Moudiz Shot in the dark, but `alter table tab1 add col1 datetime default getdate() null`. Theoretically any null value should become the  default, but I'm not an expert on Sybase.

Comment: @JonStirling I want it not null , and when I run the query it is throwing an error. ( the error is mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my question  by adding the column to null

```
alter table tab1 add col1 datetime default getdate() null
```

then I modify it to not null

Answer (score 0):

Use the below for `Sybase` :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD effective_date Datetime DEFAULT "3/16/2009 09:15" NOT NULL


ALTER TABLE table_name
REPLACE effective_date DEFAULT getdate()
```